# How to display filter in google analytics

Tags: filter, google-analytics, report, subdirectory

I have a google analytics account for one domain, lets call it MyDomain, on this Domain there is a subfolder (/MySubFolder/) that I would like reports for. I therefore created a filter in the admin tab - view - filter that filter out data based on . How can I create one report that show data based on this filter, and one report that only show data for the top domain (without the subfolder)?

Comment: This is not about coding. Please repost to Webmasters forum.